# adding image over another image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to develop an appstore. I want to add a label (like "new" or "hot" labels) on top of the icons automatically. like this image
[image]

How is it possible? I mean I can change visibility of the image but android layout doesn't let an image view on top of the other. So how is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two image views in RelativeLayout or FrameLayout so that they overlap, then set one of them `android:visibility="gone"`. Set them to visible when you want.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/image"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    android:rotation="20" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/image"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:rotation="20"
    android:text="New"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just offering you another solution which I believe is more portable and, somehow provide you a less messy xml layout files.

```
public static Bitmap combineBitmaps(Bitmap base, Bitmap label, Context context) {
    if (base == null || label == null) {
        System.err.println("Bitmap is null!");
        return null;
    }

    if(base.getWidth() != label.getWidth() || base.getHeight() != label.getHeight()){
        System.err.println("Width or height mismatch!");
        return null;
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(base);
    canvas.drawBitmap(label, 0f, 0f, null);

    return base;
}
```